# Number of queries required to find the function.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

this is a slight variation to [question $3$](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=1&cid=253&year=2010&sid=23e8e7266583d38e36b86e395844408d) of the Nordic mathematical olympiad of 2010.(in short that one deals with bijections and this one deals with any kind of function).We have 2010 buttons and 2010 bulbs.

In this variation we have 2010 buttons, each of them connected to exactly one bulb. However it could be that some bulbs are connected to many buttons and some bulbs connected to no buttons. As in the other question, a move consists in pressing several buttons simultaneously and seeing which of them light up. (A bulb lights up if at least one of its buttons is pressed). How many moves must Alice make to guarantee she can figure out to which bulb each button is connected?

Comment: Please clarify -- Does a button connect to exactly one bulb or can it possibly connect to multiple bulbs?

Comment: each button is connected to exacty one bulb

Comment: The number of buttons is not less then the number of bulbs. Consider the particular case when every button is connected one particular bulb. I believe, we would require 2010 moves to figure this out (which is like the worst case scenario -- loosely speaking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the same as when we only had with bijections.  To solve the problem label each of the buttons with the numbers from $1$ to $2010$ in binary, you will need $11$ digits. After this has been done start by pressing the buttons with $1$ as the first digit, then press the numbers with $1$ as their second digit, and so on $11$ times. Given a bulb you know all of the digits of the button being connected to it, so you can solve the problem.

To see the answer is indeed $11$ suppose the function is a bijection. If you do $10$ or less pressings there are at most $2^{10}<2010$  responses a bulb could have had, then there exists two bulbs that have reacted identically to all the pressings, if the function is a bijection we have no way of knowing which of those two bulbs is connected to which button.