# Finding a separating family of subsets of $[n]$ of size $n+1$.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, coding-theory

I have this friend who always tells me problems I can't solve. Here is the latest one. We are given a family $\mathcal F$ of at least $2^{n-1}+1 $ subsets  $[n]$. We must prove that we can $\color{blue}{\text{select}}$ $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil +1$ of the subsets in $\mathcal F$ such that if we pick two elements of $[n]$ there is a $\color{blue}{\text{selected}}$ subset that contains exactly one of those two elements.

Here are some observations: The bound is sharp. If $\mathcal F$ has $2^{n-1}$ subsets we can let $\mathcal F$ be the family of subsets of $[n]$ that have both $n$ and $n-1$ or none of those two elements and then no selection satisfies the problem. I think this is related to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852831/number-of-queries-required-to-find-the-function)

Comment: Can you clarify the $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil + 1$ part? Where are you actually using it in the question?

Comment: Nope. Still not clear. Are you selecting $\log_2 n + 1$ subsets? (you have it written as elements). Is your question: I can select $\log_2 + 1$ subsets, and given any two elements of $[n]$ you select, one of my selected subsets will only have one of the elements you have selected?

Comment: Yes, clearer now.

Comment: Does $[n]$ stand for the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$? I vaguely recall somebody saying that this is standard in computer science contexts. In my youth the bracket function was (and to many it still is) the floor function. In this context that does not make sense, though :-)

Comment: Can your friend point to a source? I'm not suspecting any foul play in this case, but a contest question could be from an ongoing contest, and many of us are a bit sensitive about those. Mind you, those wanting to cheat usually don't use the contest-math tag :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $[n]$ is the set $\{1,2,3,\dots n\}$. I'll ask him the next time I see him. It's probably from an undergrad competition like Putnam or something.

Comment: It is from the 2014 Miklós Schweitzer Memorial Competition in Mathematics ( http://www.bolyai.hu/SCH_angol_2014.pdf )

Comment: If you make represent each member of $F$ by its characteristic function, then you can get a matrix out of it. Then after selection, you get two elements corresponding to two columns, and the inclusion of exactly 1 will means that xor of those two columns is none zero (at one of the rows). This looks a lot like a hamming code in which no two columns of the generator matrix are the same (min distance 3). Now you only have to show you can pick a subject that is a hamming code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an algebraic proof.

It suffices to consider the case when $n = 2^k$ is a power of $2$ (we can reduce to this case by appending dummy elements to $[n]$). We arbitrarily identify $[2^k]$ with the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^k$.

For each $v \in \mathbb{F}_2^k$, we select a $e_v \in \mathbb{F}_2$. For each $w \in \mathbb{F}_2^k \backslash \{0\}$, let
$$V_w = \{v \in \mathbb{F}_2^k: v \cdot w = e_v\}.$$
We call $w$ **good** if $V_w \in F$.

The proof relies on two claims.

**Claim 1**: there exists a choice of $e_v$ such that more than half of $w \in \mathbb{F}_2^k \backslash \{0\}$ are good.

Proof: We select $e_v$ uniformly and independently at random. Then for each individual $w \in \mathbb{F}_2^k \backslash \{0\}$, $V_w$ is a uniformly random subset of $\mathbb{F}_2^k$. So we have
$$\mathbb{P}(w \text{ good}) = |F| / 2^{2^k} > 1/2.$$
Summing over $w$, and using linearity of expectation, we get
$$\mathbb{E}(\# w \text{ good}) > (2^k - 1) / 2$$
so we can find some choice of $e_v$ such that more than half of $w $ are good.

Now fix such a choice of $e_v$.

**Claim 2**: We can find good $w_1, \cdots, w_{k + 1}$ such that $w_2 - w_1, w_3 - w_1, \cdots, w_{k + 1} - w_1$ form a basis of $\mathbb{F}_2^k$.

Proof: Let $S$ be the set of good $w$. Choose $w_1 \in S$ arbitrarily. Then $S - w_1$ has size greater than $2^{k - 1}$, so it is not contained in any proper subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^k$. Thus we can find a basis in $S - w_1$, as desired.

Finally, we claim that $V_{w_1}, \cdots, V_{w_{k + 1}}$ are the desired subsets. Indeed, suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{F}_2^k$ satisfy that $a \in V_{w_i}$ iff $b \in V_{w_i}$ for each $i$. Then we easily get
$$a \cdot w_i - e_a = b \cdot w_i - e_b.$$
So for any $i$, we have
$$(a - b) \cdot (w_i - w_1) = 0.$$
Thus $a - b = 0$, as desired.